# Filtering emojis in input

Tags: php, preg-replace, emoji

I currently have a form that allows user to insert comments into MySQL database.

Is there a method to **filter emoji entry** in PHP before the string is inserted into MySQL?

Can I use `preg_replace()` or is there a better function to use?

This emoji:

Is converted to this after inserting into MySQL:

```
ðŸŽ
```

---

**Example:**

Input: `This is a present`

Output: `This is a present`

---

**HTML Form:**

```
<input name="remarks" type="text" placeholder="Optional"/>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];

$remarks = preg_replace('/\xEE[\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|\xEF[\x81-\x83][\x80-\xBF]/', '', $remarks);
```

*(This pattern does not work)*

Comment: how about the answer? Can you give me a reply?

Comment: @Andreas I'll try it later, forgot about this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but I will give it a try.

```
preg_match_all("/(\W)+/", "This is a present ", $output_array);
```

Output:

```
preg_match_all("/(\w)+/", "This is a present ", $output_array);
```

Output:

```
array(2
      0 =>  array(4
          0 =>  This
          1 =>  is
          2 =>  a
          3 =>  present
      )
```

So basically match words and non words in two different regex.

Comment: @luweiqi Any comment on this?